# How many ways letter can be placed in the box?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 6 letters and 6 boxes numbered 1 to 6 , letters are to placed in the box such that letter having number 1 should not be placed in box having number 1 and so on. Letter 1 is fixly placed in box 2.What is possible ways letter can be placed in boxes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the condition that $1$ must go into box $2$, this is the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) of $6$, which is well known to be $\frac{6!}{0!}-\frac{6!}{1!}+\frac{6!}{2!}-\frac{6!}{3!}+\frac{6!}{4!}-\frac{6!}{5!}+\frac{6!}{6!} = 360-120+30-6+1 =265$. (Various methods are known to find that formula, see the link.) Since the specification is symmetric under renumbering letters and boxes simultaneously by any permutation, there are as many solutions where $1$ goes to $2$ as there are where it goes to any fixed one of $3$, $4$, $5$, or$~6$. So for the indicated problem divide by $5$ giving $\frac{265}5=53$ as answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a well known problem, and usually a hard one for beginners. Please look up [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: Can you edit your answer by giving logical explanation of this sum of what to do besides derangement.

Comment: @MurtuzaVadharia: That's the only efficient way I know of doing this problem. Of course, you may try to list out all the possibilities.. and good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the solution is 53.

Derangements on 6 elements would be $6! / e$ rounded towards nearest integer = 265.

It is slightly different from derangements because of the fix of letter 1 in second box. There were 5 (hopefully) equally distributed options for the second box, but only 1 is chosen, so take $1/5$ of 265 to get 53.

Otherwise you'd have to split the cases and apply inclusion/exclusion.

On a scratch paper I already did this, and it seems right.

Comment: Your answer is right. The answer is also calculable as $!5+!4 = 44+9=53$. The reason is that if letter 2 is placed in box 1, the remaining options are the derangements of 4, and if letter 2 avoids box 1, it's a substitute for letter 1 in the derangements of 5.

Comment: That was the incredibly smart answer I knew existed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inclusion-exclusion theorem: Clearly total number of permutations is 6!. Fix the first box and permute the remaining, then the second box and so on. Since you have overcounted, you need to add back the cases when 2 boxes are fixed. The number of such permutation is $\binom{6}{2} 4!$, and so on. You should get 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{6}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{6}{k}(6-k)!
$$